# I have a string date yyyymm in my bean and want to compare with present month or previous Calendar Date

Tags: java, string, calendar

I have a java bean with `String month`, that holds a `"YYYYMM"` value.

I want to compare that value with the current month or previous month using calendar dates. I don't know how to do that.

Currently, in the `DateBean` bean class I am using a below property like:

```
private String month;
```

in the `List<DateBean>` this gives me `"YYYYMM"` format values, eg `201906`.

I want to compare it with current calender date to check the month is current one or not.

How can I do that?

Comment: I would deal solely with a range dates, not "months". eg `2019-06-01` and `2019-06-30`, then use classes from the `java.time` package to determine if the current date (ie `LocalDate.now()`) is between (inclusive) the range.

Comment: `YearMonth.parse( "201901" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMM" ) ).equals( YearMonth.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) )`  See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/h5KFkZ).

Comment: @Bohemian Actually, Java does offer the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class to deal with a month as a whole. That is one reason to re-open this Question.

Comment: @Basil - your code is cool. I've re-opened the question so you can post it as an answer,

Comment: Don’t keep date and time data in strings in your program. Use proper date types. In this case obviously the `YearMonth` class already mentioned. Whenever your program accepts string input, parse it into a properly typed object first thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you keep an integer value in *a string* in your bean? A floating-point value? Of course you wouldn’t. Then why a month value? Of course you won’t do that either. You want:

```
private YearMonth month;
```

The `YearMonth` class is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. When your program accepts date and time data as a string, parse it into the appropriate date-time type. You may find it convenient to have a constructor for that, for example:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMM");

public DateBean(String month) {
    this.month = YearMonth.parse(month, monthFormatter);
}
```

Comparing simply uses the `equals` method of `YearMonth`, for example:

```
    List<DateBean> dateBeans
            = List.of(new DateBean("201901"), new DateBean("201906"));
    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Sofia"));
    for (DateBean bean : dateBeans) {
        if (bean.getMonth().equals(currentMonth)) {
            System.out.println("" + bean.getMonth() + " is current month");
        } else {
            System.out.println("" + bean.getMonth() + " is not current month");
        }
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2019-01 is not current month
> 2019-06 is current month
> ```

Since the new month doesn’t start at the same point in all time zones, I recommend you pass your desired time zone to `YearMonth.now()`.

**Edit:** Basil Bourque may have an excellent point in his comment: If the sole purpose of your `DateBean` class was to wrap your year and month strings, you are probably better off *replacing* it with `YearMonth` completely than *wrapping* a `YearMonth`.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Superb answer. But I wonder if `YearMonth` might eliminate the need for their `DateBean` class. I suspect they may have been trying to invent the functionality provided by `YearMonth`.

Comment: Superb question, @BasilBourque. I have edited in a note at the end of my Answer.